# Ebean update() never returns

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I am using Play Framework 2.2 (Java version) and Ebean together with a local installation of PostgreSQL. In one of my model classes, `MyClass`, which has a `boolean` field called `active`, I have a method, `myMethod`, looking something like this:

```
public void myMethod() {
    Logger.info("Start");
    active = true;
    update();
    Logger.info("End");
}
```

For some reason, the call to `update()` never returns, so my log simply prints

```
[info] application - Start
```

and then no more: the corresponding page in the browser is never loaded and just waits indefinitely. If I turn on database logging, I can see the prepared statement:

```
[debug] c.j.b.PreparedStatementHandle - update myclass set active=true where [...]
```

which looks correct.

Has anyone encountered this problem or has an idea for how to investigate it?

I suspect that there may be some kind of lock on the database. If I open pgAdmin and try to manually insert TRUE in the active column, the result is that pgAdmin stalls and has to be force closed.

Comment: check: `update(this.id);`

Comment: Tried it, and it does not change anything.